# Python create a new column with extracted regex until \n from a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have a data frame like this below:

```
data = {'c1':['Level:     LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 01\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement 1\n', 
              'Level: NOT_LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 01\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement 3\n', 
              'Level:     LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 02\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement2\n', 
              'Level: NOT_LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 04\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement1\n'],
        'c2':["one", "two", "three", "four"]}
```

I would like to create:

- a regex that extract anything after `Thrown: lib:` until the first `\n`. I will call this "group 01". So I will have this below:

  ```
  data = {'c3':['this is problem type 01', 
                 'this is problem type 01', 
                 'this is problem type 02', 
                 'this is problem type 04']}
  ```
- and then I want to create a regex that extract everything after "group 01"(the previous regex), ignoring the `\t` and `\n` that is between the sentences and going until the next `\n`. So I will have this below:

  ```
  data = {'c4':['Error executing the statement: error statement 1', 
              'Error executing the statement: error statement 3', 
              'Error executing the statement: error statement2', 
              'Error executing the statement: error statement1']}
  ```

In the end I want my dataframe to be like this:

```
data = {'c1':['Level:     LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 01\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement 1', 
              'Level: NOT_LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 01\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement 3', 
              'Level:     LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 02\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement2', 
              'Level: NOT_LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 04\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement1'],
        'c3':['this is problem type 01', 
              'this is problem type 01', 
              'this is problem type 02', 
              'this is problem type 04'],
        'c4':['Error executing the statement: error statement 1', 
              'Error executing the statement: error statement 3', 
              'Error executing the statement: error statement2', 
              'Error executing the statement: error statement1'],
        'c2':["one", "two", "three", "four"]}
```

This is what I have so far, I was trying to extract from "`Thrown: lib:`" until the first `\n`, but it do not works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['exception'] = df['c1'].str.extract(r'Thrown: lib: (.*(?:\r?\n.*)*)', expand=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could probably do it as one-liner, but something like this:

```
import re
import pandas as pd


data = {'c1':['Level:     LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 01\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement 1\n', 
              'Level: NOT_LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 01\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement 3\n', 
              'Level:     LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 02\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement2\n', 
              'Level: NOT_LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 04\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement1\n'],
        'c2':["one", "two", "three", "four"]}



df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pattern1 = 'Thrown: lib: ([a-zA-Z\d\s]*)\\n'
df['c3'] = df['c1'].str.extract(pattern1, expand=False).str.strip()

pattern2 = '(\\n\s\\t){1,}(.*)\\n'
df['c4'] = df['c1'].str.extract(pattern2, expand=True)[1]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
                                                                                                                           c1     c2                       c3                                                c4
0  Level:     LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 01\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement 1\n    one  this is problem type 01  Error executing the statement: error statement 1
1  Level: NOT_LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 01\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement 3\n    two  this is problem type 01  Error executing the statement: error statement 3
2   Level:     LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 02\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement2\n  three  this is problem type 02   Error executing the statement: error statement2
3   Level: NOT_LOGGING_ONLY\n Thrown: lib: this is problem type 04\n \t\n \tError executing the statement: error statement1\n   four  this is problem type 04   Error executing the statement: error statement1
```

Comment: Hello Hello, thanks for the update!  I didn't understand your regex but it didn't work when I tested I think. Like, the c4 is this as you said, moreover it has to be after the "group 01" as I wrote on the initial question. This means, it should have the separator \n \t\n just after 'Thrown: lib:' to work, otherwise will match the  \n \t\n  that exist before the "group 01" to happen.  (i need the first \n \t\n just after 'Thrown: lib:')  :)

Comment: I was able to change your second pattern to do what I wanted like this: pattern2 = 'Thrown: lib.gack.GackContext: [^\n]+(\\n\s\\t){1,}(.*)\\n'.  Thank you :)

Comment: Could you be able to explain the second pattern? I was able to modify by try-and-error but I will be happy to understand better the regex :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `re` package:

```
data['c3'] = [re.findall("Thrown: lib: ([^\n]+)", x) for x in data['c1']]
data['c4'] = [re.split("\n", x)[3].strip() for x in data['c1']]
```

- The first pattern extract everything between `Thrown: lib:`  and the first newline
- the second pattern assume that the relevant message is always the 4th token, when split by `\n`, which seems to be the case

**FOLLOW UP**: following question below.
The pattern for `data['c4']` is based on the fact that the message is always after 4 "`\n`" newlines in the message. 
Now, if the separator of interest is "`\n \t\n`", you can modify the pattern in:

```
data['c4'] = [re.split("\n \t\n", x)[1].strip() for x in data['c1']]
```

or

```
data['c4'] = [re.findall(".*?\n \t\n(.*)", x)[0].strip() for x in data['c1']]
```

THe last approach is better given that, if the `split` fails on the separator, you'll get an `IndexError`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! Got the first pattern, it works :) Moreover the second is after a "\n \t\n \t", not just after a \n. Do you have any tips on how to change for accepting it? :)